# airodump-ng mon0 not woking with eth2 interface

Tags: networking, aircrack-ng

I am new to ubuntu os.I have installed aircrack successfully and trying to execute the  command  `sudo airodump-ng mon0` but its not working.How to fix this issue ?

Error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo airmon-ng start waln0


Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e 
PID Name
1382    avahi-daemon
1383    avahi-daemon
1433    NetworkManager
14727   wpa_supplicant


Interface   Chipset     Driver

eth2        Unknown         wl

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo airodump-ng mon0
Interface mon0: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
```

also tried with eth2 interface but no luck!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo airmon-ng start eth2
```

iwconfig

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:5  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0

ppp0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 0):

The system is telling you exactly what the problem is:

```
Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
1382    avahi-daemon
1383    avahi-daemon
1433    NetworkManager
14727   wpa_supplicant
```

You want to kill all of the above processes (by using `kill <PID>` as a superuser).

After that, everything else should work just as expected.

Comment: No killing is not solving the issue!

Comment: @user2252617 Have you tried it with your `eth2` interface?

Comment: ya tried but no luck